# ActiveRecords Associations: undefined method for nil:NilClass

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-3, rails-activerecord, model-associations

first of all this is my first Rails application, so please be indulgent... I read the Rails Guides for associations in http://guides.rubyonrails.org/association_basics.html and then started to code my own project. My problem is that I can't do stuff like @project.user.email because @project.user seems to be nil all the time. This happen for all objects. @user.role.name also throws "undefined method for nil:NilClass"; I'm sure I'm doing wrong someting with the models definitions but I don't understand what it is. I appreciate your help. Thanks.

```
   class Role < ActiveRecord::Base
      has_many :users
      attr_accessible :name
   end

   class User < ActiveRecord::Base
      belongs_to :role
      has_many :projects
      attr_accessible :email, :password, :password_confirmation, :role_id, :role  
   end

   class Project < ActiveRecord::Base
      belongs_to :user
      belongs_to :project_type
      attr_accessible :id, :project_type_id, :title, :description  
   end

   class Project_Type < ActiveRecord::Base
      has_many :projects
      attr_accessible :name
   end
```

An example would be for instance the index view for projects where I do (HAML):

```
   %td= proyecto.user.email
```

which wouldn't work. However,

```
   %td= proyecto.user_id
```

does work fine.

Comment: Please include the code that produces the error.

Comment: for `@project.user`: Do you have `user_id` in projects table? And for `@user.role`: remove `:role` from **attr_accessible** in user model.

Comment: @MrTheWalrus In the scaffold view for projects/index, I'm doing this (HAML): %td= project.user.email ...this doesn't work, but project.user_id does.

Comment: Thanks @SybariteManoj , yes... I have user_id in projects table.

Comment: first - you dont need attr_accessible for :id. Second - provide code that returns you error. And in your case you more likely need habtm relationts

Comment: Ok.. try `%td= project.user.inspect` in your view and tell us what do you get.

Comment: @sannySin could you give me an example or be a little more specific about how habtm relations should work? thanks.

Comment: I can't really find a reason why it returns nil when the project have the user_id and the user with user_id exists. :(

Answer (score 2, accepted):

When you create a new Project, all of the associations will default to nil unless you have setup some type of default in your migrations. There are a few things you can do there.

First, you can set the user manually:

```
@user = User.find(5)
@project = Project.new
@project.user = @user
```

Additionally, you can build new projects from the user. The `build` method is added automatically from the `has_many` association.

```
@user = User.find(5)
@project = @user.projects.build
```

Now `@project` will contain a project associated with the user who has id 5. You also need to be sure that you tell Rails what the associations are, otherwise the associations won't work.

Comment: I'm  doing this in the controller:
  def index
    @projects = Project.all
  end 
and then using project.user.email in the view which doesn't work, but project.user_id does...